# ie9 showing weird spacing in div

Tags: css, html

So here is where the page is hosted: *see comment*

The problem is in the bottom content box titled 'Mortgage Recent News', you'll notice how the borders of the div are misaligned in ie9.  However, they are perfectly aligned in FF and Chrome.

I realize that this code isn't ideal to begin with, but it's what I have to work with.  I cannot include the images in any part of the `ul` as it's generated by a backend script that we do not have access to.

I'm just looking for a way to fix the current code so that it looks the same on ie9 as it does on FF and Chrome right now.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: don't we all love ie? I'm getting a untrusted connection error on that link.

Comment: The link makes Google Chrome show its malware alert page!

Comment: It's because it's an SSL link but it's a site that's currently in migration. It's not a dirty link.

Comment: ugh, im going to delete the link and see if I can get a non-SSL version ready.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem.  Basically I needed to specify both the padding and height of each li in the css instead of letting the browser default.  Works now.